# Корректный способ защиты множества объектов от изменений

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, ооп

Нужно написать приложение, которые моделирует некоторые физические процессы. Будет написан некоторый класс `Simulation`, содержащий основные методы управления процессом моделирования (например метод `Step()`). Все операции в конечном итоге будут производиться над множеством (`HashSet<Atom>`) объектов типа `Atom`. Над этим множеством после моделирования надо производить различные действия, к классу `Simulation` не относящиеся (да и перед моделированием это множество надо соорудить отдельно или откуда-то загрузить). В процессе моделирования (то есть пока будет выполняться метод `Step()`) множество атомов желательно как-то защитить от воздействия извне, т. е. запретить добавление / удаление атомов, изменение их свойств.

Можно сделать `HashSet<Atom>` полем класса `Simulation`, определив так же методы `Add(Atom atom)`, `Remove(Atom atom)` и т. п. А для защиты изменения в процессе моделирования использовать `if (locked) return`.

```
public class Simulation
{
    private readonly HashSet<Atom> _atoms = new HashSet<Atom>();

    . . .

    private bool locked;     

    public bool Add(Atom atom)
    {
        if (locked) return false;
        if (atom == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(atom));
        return _atoms.Add(atom);
    }

    public bool Remove(Atom atom)
    {
        if (locked) return false;
        return _atoms.Remove(atom);
    }

    public void Step(float dt)
    {
        locked = true;

        . . .

        locked = false;
    }

    . . .

}
```

Но такой подход не позволяет защитить атомы от изменения во время моделирования если ссылки на них есть где-то вне множества `_atoms`.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно разрешить данную проблему.**

---

**EDIT**

Атом представляет собой следующий класс:

```
[Serializable]
public class Atom
{
    private static int _numberOfInstances;

    [NonSerialized] private readonly int _hashCode;

    public Atom()
    {
        _hashCode = Interlocked.Increment(ref _numberOfInstances);
    }

    [field: NonSerialized] internal Vector3 Acceleration { get; set; }
    [field: NonSerialized] internal Vector3 Displacement { get; set; }

    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Velocity { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _hashCode;
    }
}
```

И защищать тут нужно свойства `Position` и `Velocity`.

Comment: Точно так же, как Вы уже показали. Добавить поле `locked` в `Atom` и проверять его во всех сетерах свойств.

Comment: @Igor, определив его как `internal`? Или можно как-то более изящно сделать его изменяемым только для класса `Simulation`?

Comment: Это уже зависит от того, как классы организованы в библиотеки(-у). Да, `internal` - приемлемое решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант 1.

Точно так же, как Вы уже показали. Добавить поле `locked` в `Atom` и проверять его во всех сетерах свойств.

Вариант 2.

Склонировать набор атомов в новые объекты, на которые ни у кого нет ссылок, и работать с ними.

Answer (score 5):

Если атомы - простые структуры и не содержат внутри себя ничего изменяемого, то можно сделать интерфейс только для чтения

```
public interface IReadonlyAtom
{
    int Id {get;}
    string Name{get;}
}
```

Написать реализацию атома

```
public class Atom : IReadonlyAtom
{
    public int Id {get;private set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public Atom(int id, string name = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    // не забудьте перегрузки equals и gethashcode 
    // если будете делать hashset с атомами
}
```

И сделать симуляцию полным владельцем коллекции атомов. То есть внешний код никак не сможет менять атомы или влиять как то ещё на них напрямую.

```
public class Simulation
{
    private readonly HashSet<Atom> _atoms = new HashSet<UserQuery.Atom>();

    public void AddAtom(int id, string name = null)
    {
        _atoms.Add(new Atom(id, name));
    }

    // Наружу отдаем коллекцию только для чтения с атомами только для чтения
    public IReadOnlyCollection<IReadonlyAtom> Atoms =>
            _atoms.Cast<IReadonlyAtom>().ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

Этот вариант может пригодиться в том случае, если атомов будет настолько много, что клонирование их займет много времени \ памяти.

Comment: Могли бы Вы что-нибудь посоветовать для предложенного определения атома и их количества около 10-20 тысяч?

Comment: @asyncawait 10-20 тысяч в плане памяти - ерунда, если вы не собираетесь их копировать 20 раз в секунду.